# Como fazer select no postgres a partir de um campo html e utilizar o retorno para preencher os outros campos?

Tags: php, javascript, html, postgresql

Basicamente eu não tenho experiência alguma com html, php ou javascrip e to tentando me virar no que me pedem aqui. O problema é o seguinte:

Eu tenho que fazer uma página de cadastro onde o usuário seleciona um ano base e se o registro existir no bando de dados (postgres) ele preenche os campos com os dados para atualizar, e se não existir os campos continuam vazios para adicionar o registro. São parâmetros anuais, então já da pra concluir que só pode ter um cadastro por ano. Obs.: Tudo via Post.

Eu já tenho o código que realiza a conexão  com o BD, só incluir onde precisar, e também tenho uma ligeira noção dos comandos de sql, não é tão difícil. Queria mesmo uma orientação, não tenho ideia do que pesquisar nem por onde começar a pesquisar. Não quero códigos nem nada (a menos que seja pra exemplificar, ajuda um pouco), queria mesmo saber o que preciso aprender pra conseguir fazer isso, até porquê é uma dúvida muito genérica.

Answer (score 1):

Te aconselho a dar uma lida sobre AJAX com JQUERY.

O fluxo será mais ou menos o seguinte:

1. Usuário digita a data.
2. Com o JQUERY e seus eventos (onkeypress, up etc) verifica se a data está completa.
3. Se estiver completa, fazer uma chamada a um script do PHP utilizando ajax (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).
4. Nesse script PHP vai fazer a query pesquisando em seu banco de dados (SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE data = '$data').
5. Caso essa query retorne uma linha ou não, crie um JSON com o resultado
6. Com o JSON criado, é só dar um "echo" nele mesmo Ex.: echo $json.
7. Com isso o nosso ajax irá receber esse JSON no retorno, (função success), no retorno você faz o tratamento dos dado. Dica: De uma lida no site da W3SCHOOLS.
8. Tratando os dados setamos os valores nos inpunts que desejamos.

Um exemplo básico fazendo um fluxo parecido: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm